# Docker cannot run on build when running container with a different user

Tags: node.js, bash, docker

I don't know the specifics why the node application does not run. Basically I added a dockerfile in a nodejs app, and here is my Dockerfile

```
 FROM node:0.10-onbuild
 RUN mv /usr/src/app /ghost && useradd ghost --home /ghost && \
 cd /ghost
 ENV NODE_ENV production
 VOLUME ["/ghost/content"]
 WORKDIR /ghost
 EXPOSE 2368
 CMD ["bash", "start.bash"]
```

Where `start.bash` looks like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 GHOST="/ghost"
 chown -R ghost:ghost /ghost
 su ghost << EOF
 cd "$GHOST"
 NODE_ENV={$NODE_ENV:-production} npm start
 EOF
```

I usually run docker like so:

```
 docker run --name ghost -d -p 80:2368 user/ghost
```

With that I cannot see what is going on, and I decided to run it like this:

```
 docker run --name ghost -it -p 80:2368 user/ghost
```

And I got this output:

```
 > ghost@0.5.2 start /ghost
 > node index
```

Seems, like starting, but as I check the status of the container `docker ps -a` , it is stopped.

Here is the repo for that but, the start.bash and dockerfile is different, because I haven't committed the latest, since both are not working:

[JoeyHipolito/Ghost](https://github.com/joeyhipolito/ghost/tree/feature/dockerize)

Comment: Can you try appending `bash` to your command and then running `bash start.bash` manually? What you do is a bit unusual (although I don't know why it doesn't work), to get the output of the running process use `docker logs ghost`.

Comment: haha, really? why do you find it unusual, i'll do what you suggest then

Comment: `docker logs ghost` gave the same output as my `-it` attempt...

Comment: sometimes there are things that make you crazy, suddenly it works now, I guess **I forgot to build it again before running**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to make it work, there is no error in the `start bash` file nor in the `Dockerfile`, it's just that I failed to build the image again.

With that said, you can checkout the final `Dockerfile` and `start.bash` file in my repository:

[Ghost-blog__Docker (https://github.com/joeyhipolito/ghost)](https://github.com/joeyhipolito/ghost)

At the time I write this answer, you can see it in the feature-branch, `feature/dockerize`.